# How to include min and max value pf a particular variable in r ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linegraph

[image]

I have tried many things but was not able to include the min and maximum value of GDP in each countries line graph.

Comment: But there _are_ maximum and minimum values of GDP in your plot. Or are you just trying to recreate this plot? If so, please show the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

There already *are* maximum and minimum values of GDP in your plot. Or are you just trying to recreate this plot?  If so, the following code gets you very close:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

gapminder %>%
  filter(country %in% c("Canada", "Japan", "Jordan", "United States")) %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1962, 1982, 2002)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(year), gdpPercap, color = country, group = country)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(size = 5, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(year == 2002), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.1,
            size = 5, key_glyph = draw_key_blank,
            aes(label = scales::dollar(round(gdpPercap)))) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(year == 1962), hjust = 1, nudge_x = -0.1,
            size = 5, key_glyph = draw_key_blank,
            aes(label = scales::dollar(round(gdpPercap)))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  labs(title = "A comparison of GDP", 
       subtitle = "GDP per capita change 1962 - 2002",
       caption = "Source: Gapminder dataset") +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.05),
        axis.text.x = element_text(),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20),
        plot.title = element_text(face = 2),
        plot.subtitle =  element_text(face = 2, margin = margin(10, 0, 50, 0)),
        plot.caption =  element_text(face = 2, margin = margin(30, 30, 30, 30)))
```

[image]

Comment: can you round the values of gdp per cap in the graph

Comment: and there is letter a in the legends. we can see that if we look closely

Comment: @JicksonThomas yes, they are also in the original plot. Is this your plot or are you trying to copy it? You never answered that in my original comment. If you want to round `gdpPercap` do `scales::dollar(round(gdpPercap))` instead of `scales::dollar(gdpPercap)`  in the geom_text call. To get rid of the letters in the legend add the argument`key_glyph = draw_key_none` in the geom_text call.

Comment: the letter a is not going away any other option????

Comment: @JicksonThomas it does go away. I have amended my answer with rounded dollar values and absent key glyphs in the text layers to demonstrate. My exact code will produce the exact same results.